# count in mysql update mysql query, error support

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, join

hello need a update starting from..

```
 SELECT 
     tA.id, count(*) c
FROM
    tA
        join
    tA ON tB.id = tA.id
where
    tA.id = 5
GROUP BY tA.id
having c > 1;
```

I have a relational model one to many. but need include the count in the update

```
   UPDATE tA
        join
    tA ON tB.id = tA.id 
set 
    cnt = 5;
```

assuming that this is the result of the count

where 'c' is the first select count... may be.

```
UPDATE tA
        join
    tA ON tB.id = tA.id 
set 
    cnt = (SELECT 
            count(*) c
        FROM
            tA
                join
            tA ON tB.id = tA.id
        WHERE
            tA.id = 5
        GROUP BY tA.id
        having c > 1);
```

say query syntax  nor supported.. thnk

Comment: what table does this column `cantidad` belong? `cnt`?

Comment: @geronimo76 . . . All your queries are clearly incorrect because they use `tB` and that is not defined anywhere.  Can you fix your question?

Comment: cnt is the column the Table A

Comment: this is a typo `tA
        join
    tA ON tB.id = tA.id` right? it should be `tA
        join
    tB ON tB.id = tA.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  tA
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  tA.id, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    tA INNER JOIN tB ON tB.id = tA.id
            WHERE   tA.id = 5
            GROUP   BY tA.id
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON tA.id = b.id
SET     tA.cnt = b.totalCount
```